# Bluetooth Speaker No sound Issues

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

So  I have been using the same Bluetooth speaker (the Sony srs-xb3) for years on my previous PC build (using the EkoBuy® Bluetooth 4.0 USB Dongle Adapter for PC) since my motherboard had no  internal Bluetooth compatibility. I recently built my second PC which has Bluetooth built into the motherboard (Z370 AORUS ULTRA GAMING WIFI) but my speaker isn't being detected by it, so I continued using the adapter. The adapted detects my speaker but wont play audio. I have tried troubleshooting the speaker which does turn the audio on but only through hands free mode which sounds awful. I did manage to get the speaker working on my PC once but I'm not sure how and then on restart it proceeded to revert to having the same issues. I have tried updating the drivers on everything, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be able to connect to the speaker via bluetooth, the next thing I would check is what Audio Playback device is set as the default.  To check this, navigate to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound and you will see a box that looks like this:
[image]

You should see the connected bluetooth speaker listed on the playback device list.  Right click on the device and select "Set as default device".  You can also right click the device and select "test" to send a test chime to the speaker.  If you right click the device and select "Properties", there may be a tab for "Levels" which allows you to set the volume output from the computer (not sure whether bluetooth devices have this option).  Lastly, ensure the volume on the speaker itself is loud enough to hear.